# Add annotation to pdf android

Tags: android

I want to display pdf in android for that i have user some libraries like vudroid,pdfreader but all these libraries show pdf pages as image i want to implement such functionality that user can view pdf and select text from pdf change background color of text using color picker and save the existing pdf, i have referred some of libraries but they doesn't provide such functionality,please give some idea if such library is available

I have used following libraries

```
Android PDF Viewer
APDFViewer
droidreader
```

Thanks

Comment: No i found the libraries that just display pdfs but not for annotation,you can find pdftron library which allows to add annotation,but may be it is paid

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm a developer on the PSPDFKit team

[PSPDFKit for Android](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2015/pspdfkit-android-2-0/) was recently released as version 2.0 including annotation editing support. We've spent a lot of time in making annotation editing easy – both for developers integrating PDFs in their apps, as for end users. Here is an example of how to create a NoteAnnotation with PSPDFKit:

```
PSPDFDocument document =  ...

// Create the annotation.
final int pageNum = 3;
final RectF pagePosition = new RectF(10, 10, 30, 30);
final NoteAnnotation annotation = new NoteAnnotation(pageNum, pagePosition, "This is a note with cross icon!", CROSS);

// Attach the annotation to the document.
document.getAnnotationProvider().addAnnotationToPage(annotation);
```

There's also a bunch of ready-to-use UI components for annotation creation and editing. PSPDFKit is a commercial product, but we offer demo versions which can be [requested on our website](https://pspdfkit.com/#trynow).

Comment: Hey David, I'm attempting to use the PSPDFKit android library inside a custom fragmentactivity containing a viewpager. Is there a way to enable the annotations actionitem without extending PSPDFKitActivity? Otherwise, is there a way to use an activity without first providing a Uri?